# RPM application details page

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm

Is there a details page for RPMs like there is for [Debian packages](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/apache2)
I want to automate package installation and show users pertinent information about the package. I've seen there's an old rpm2html but it seems like there should be something more official hosted by the repos.

Comment: There is the `repoview` package/tool but that isn't exactly the same I don't think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details page? While packages.debian.org cover "Debian" packages, it does not cover Ubuntu packages and other derivates.

RPM world is even bigger. RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, OpenSuse, Mandriva...

For Red Hat Enterprise Linux there exists https://access.redhat.com/management/ (subscribers only).

For Fedora there is https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/

I am not sure about others.

However all managements systems (like Red Hat Satellite) query RPMs directly. See e.g. https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch16s03s05.html

As I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve you may as well present data about applications (which may consist of several packages). See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:AppData Current Fedora support AppData for nearly all applications.

Comment: The question posed is how the OP can derive this information, not where to look for where someone else has done it.

Comment: msuchy had it right. I would love an official web site I could point to and not have to build and maintain my own site.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following stackoverflow question touches on this topic.
https://serverfault.com/questions/239205/official-online-rpm-package-browser-search-for-centos